# how to limit size content database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to limit the size of the content database to add another content database to my web application.
Does anyone know how to do this with powershell or sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things, [MSFT support upto 4TB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx#ContentDB) size of Content DB and best practices is Content DB size should be 200GB.

I personally against the fix size of Content DB at the SQL because this will cause the problem once the Content DB will full then your site will be in trouble mostly readonly and in rare case stop working.

What I recommend you, limit the nummber the of Site collections for that content DB via Central Admin. lets say you have 1 site collection then put the 1 in max number of the site collections and 0 in warning. In this way no new site will provision in this CDB.

```
$db = Get-SPContentDatabase -Site "http://example/"
$db.MaximumSiteCount = 1
$db.WarningSiteCount = 0
$db.Update()
```

From [Central Admin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825317%28v=office.14%29.aspx) / PowerShell you can create a new content DB.

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name <ContentDbName> -WebApplication <WebApplicationName>
```

Also check this link will help you to create a site collection into own content DB.

http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2011/01/sharepoint-2010-add-site-collection-to.html